# Javascript scrollTop not working as expected

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div id="messages" class="messages"></div>
<hr>
<textarea id="contentofmessage" name="content" type="text" maxlength="320" style="box-sizing: border-box; width: 100%; height: 100px; padding: 10px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; border-radius: 5px; outline: none; border: 2px solid #D3D3D3; resize: none;" placeholder="Type your message here..."></textarea><br><br>
<button id="submit" class="btn_anchor_for_submit">Send</button>
<script>
$("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>',
                data: {content: $('#contentofmessage').val()},
            });
            loadlink();
            $("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);
        });
    });

function loadlink(){
$(document).ready(function(){
   
   $('#messages').load("https://www.example.com/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>");
   

});
}

loadlink(); // This will run on page load

        setInterval(function () {
            var scrollTarget = $('#messages');
            var pos = scrollTarget.scrollTop();
            scrollTarget.load('https://www.example.com/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>', function() {
                $('#messages').scrollTop(pos);
            });
        },5000);
</script>
```

I use some php with it, you can definitely replace it when testing yourself

### Edit!!!

My goal is to scroll the content in the div down automatically when the page loads.

Comment: There is no content in `#messages` to make it overflow, so the scrollTop setting will not do anything

Comment: Given your update, you take the `scrollTop` value and then apply it to the same element without changing it...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i am new to js actually. I took these from the internet, so, please help me!

Comment: I would if your goal was clear. If you want to scroll to the bottom set scrollTop to something bigger than the height of the element, eg. `$('#messages').scrollTop(10000)`

Comment: when I use `$("#messages").animate({ scrollTop: $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight")}, 1000);`, it works, but I do not want it to be animated.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My goal is to scroll to the bottom of the div  when the page loads :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To scroll to the bottom of the `#messages` div after each content loads, you should scroll on callback of that load... which is asynchronous (read: takes time... A couple milliseconds)

Actually, you don't. So the steps in time are:

- 1: Load request is sent
- 2: scroll is made (but the div may already be at bottom, so you do not notice it.
- 3: Load response arrives and updates the div.

To scroll without `animate()`, it would be: `$("#messages").scrollTop( $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight") )`

And if you place it as a `.load()` callback, it looks like:

```
$('#messages').load("https://www.example.com/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>", function(){$("#messages").scrollTop( $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight") )});
```

Since all this on a single line is quite hard to read and eventually maintain, I suggest:

```
let loadURL = "https://www.example.com/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>"
let loadCallback = function(){
  $("#messages").scrollTop( $('#messages').prop("scrollHeight") )
}
$('#messages').load(loadURL, loadCallback)
```

Since `.load()` is a shorthand of `$.ajax()`... The same applies. But here, the callback would be your `loadlink` function. So I suggest:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>',
  data: {content: $('#contentofmessage').val()},
  success: loadlink
});
```

You are misusing `$(document).ready(function(){})`... That is an event handler that fires when the DOM is fully loaded... So on initial page load only. Below, I only placed what is necessary in that handler.

So here is the whole code that I suggest you to try.

```
function loadlink(){
    let loadURL = "https://www.example.com/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>";
    let loadCallback = function(){
      $("#messages").scrollTop($('#messages').prop("scrollHeight"));
    }
    $('#messages').load(loadURL, loadCallback);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/contact_live_chat/chat_display.html?username=<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>',
        data: {content: $('#contentofmessage').val()},
        success: loadlink
      });
  });

  loadlink(); // This will run on page load

  setInterval(function () {
    loadlink();
  },5000);
})
```

Comment: I'll test it soon. It is too early morning right now, and it was night time when you answered, sorry for the late response.

Comment: I tweaked the `setInterval` part,  and everything works as expected! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you you should describe what do you expect exactly ? In your screenshoot you seems to be on top already.

Do you to want to scroll to the submitted message ?

```
var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages");
const { top } = objDiv.getBoundingClientRect();

window.scrollTo({ top } ); // or objDiv.scrollTo({ top });
```

Comment: My goal is to scroll to the bottom of the div when the page loads. I think I confused you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#messages').html('<h1>Hellow</>');
   window.scrollTo(0, 650);
    function loadlink(){
    $('#messages').html('<h1>Hellow</>');
  }
  loadlink();
  setInterval(function () {
                loadlink();
        },5000);
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rajtri/oL3darzf/2/)

Comment: Okay now, let me explain my whole goal. I want to display the other page chat_display.html in div #messages. And I want to reload it every 5 seconds. And I want it to scroll down automatically only once when the whole page loads. And then, on each reload of the div, i want the scroll position to stay as it is. Thats it.

Comment: I have updated fiddle...hope this will be helpful.

Comment: i see, but i only want the div to scroll down, not the whole page